# Custom controls and windows messages

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hook

I made a custom Splitter control in pure Windows API. It's made of 4 controls: the main container, the splitter and the 2 panes.

Now I needed to hook into the windows procedure in order to find out when one of its child controls was moving or resizing, so I used **SetWindowsHookEx**. I get the **WM_SIZE** messages in my hook procedure just fine, but no **WM_MOVE** messages are ever caught from my Splitter's child windows.

I tried adding a child window to a Groupbox (which I know isn't the way they're supposed to be used) just to see if the **WM_MOVE** messages were caught by the hook procedure, and they were.

So what am I missing here? What do I need to add to my Splitter window procedure so those **WM_MOVE**s get sent? Or was my error somewhere else?

PS: **SetWindowPos** does work on those child windows, it's just not catching **WM_MOVE**.

EDIT: As requested, here is the full code of the Splitter window class: http://pastebin.com/Lgvb0Vfv

Here is the part of the code that matters:

```
LRESULT WINAPI AnchorProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    CWPRETSTRUCT* theMessage = (CWPRETSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if (theMessage->message == WM_MOVE) printf ("!");
}
```

Sometime after the main window's **WM_CREATE**:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET,AnchorProc,NULL,GetCurrentThreadId());

// groupbox

HWND gb = CreateWindowEx(0,"button",NULL,BS_GROUPBOX|WS_CHILD,0,0,200,200,hwndMain,0,hInst,NULL);
HWND but = CreateWindowEx(0,"button",NULL,BS_PUSHBUTTON|WS_CHILD,0,0,40,40,gb,0,hInst,NULL);

// custom control

HWND split = CreateWindowEx(0,"FSplitterClass",NULL,WS_CHILD,200,0,200,200,hwndMain,0,hInst,NULL);
HWND pane1 = (HWND)SendMessage(split,WM_SPGETPANE,0,0);
HWND but1 = CreateWindowEx(0,"button",NULL,BS_PUSHBUTTON|WS_CHILD,0,0,40,40,pane1,0,hInst,NULL);

SetWindowPos(but, NULL, 1,1,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER); // triggers WM_MOVE
SetWindowPos(but1, NULL, 1,1,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER); // doesn't
```

Comment: Er, why don't you write your own window proc?

Comment: @Hans, there are many reasons why you would want to know when a control is moving. In my case, I am implementing Anchors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A windows hook is overkill here. Subclassing is much more efficient.
2. WM_MOVE is generated only [if the window procedure passes the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message to DefWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you cannot guarantee that, then you are not guaranteed a WM_MOVE message. Listen for WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

Comment: The button control generates a WM_MOVE when as a child of a groupbox, but not when as a child of my custom container control (which just forwards mouse input to the parent window procedure and calls DefWndProc on all the others, as you can see in the code). Although I will just subclass it, I'd like to know what's wrong with my custom control. What's so fundamentally different that makes its child not send WM_MOVE messages?

Comment: Are you sure it actually moved? A window is positioned relative to its parent, so if the relative position doesn't change, it is not considered to have moved. Also, I think if you look closer, you'll see that the button is not strictly a.child of the groupbox. It's probably just a sibling lower in the z-order.

Comment: Yep. Also, the groupbox was the parent, you can see it in the CreateWindowEx call above. Either way, I'm subclassing now, and will leave those issues for some other time.